# Passing parameter to Action from Kendo grid toolbar using pure c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik, kendo-grid

I need to add button to kendo grid toolbar which will show popup window on click. I also need to wrap this grid in a helper which will return grid with this button. The proplem is that I need to pass parameter to action which shows popup window (grid type to be specific), but I can't use razor syntax as this helper defined in *.cs file, and I can't find the way to do it by regular c#. Can I make this in some way? Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;

namespace Test.WebUI.Helpers
{

public static class ExtendedGridHelper
{

    public static Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridBuilder<T> ExtendedGrid<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, Tuple<string, string> dataAccessing)
        where T : class
    {
        return helper.Kendo().Grid<T>()
            .Name(name)
            //.DataSource(src => src.Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("GetInstances", "ExtendedGrid")))
            .DataSource(src => src.Ajax().Read(dataAccessing.Item1, dataAccessing.Item2))
            .Sortable()
            .Pageable(it => it.PageSizes(true))
            .Groupable()
            .Filterable()
            .Reorderable(it => it.Columns(true))
            .Scrollable(it => it.Virtual(true))
            .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                foreach (var property in typeof (T).GetProperties().OrderBy(it => it.Name))
                {
                    columns.Bound(property.Name).Width(150);
                }
            }
                    )


            .ToolBar(toolbar =>
            {
                toolbar.Custom().Action("ViewPopup", "ExtendedGrid").Text("Settings").HtmlAttributes(new {@class = "modal-link btn btn-success"});
            //This way it works, but I nered to pass parameter.     
            }

            );
    }




}
}
```

Here is an example of usage:

```
  @(Html.ExtendedGrid<ololo>("Grid1", new Tuple<string, string>("GetInstances", "ExtendedGrid")))
```

Comment: Can you not just put `@using Test.WebUI.Helpers` to the views where you want to use this helper?

Comment: @BenRobinson, sorry, but how will it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, maybe it will be usefull for somebody. I just added this to resources:

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
<a onclick = "show_settings()" href='#' class = "modal-link btn btn-success">Settings</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_settings(){
        $.post("/ExtendedGrid/ViewPopup/", {objectType: "~T~", userID: "~userID~", listOfColumns: "~ListOfColumns~"},
                                              function (result) { $('#modal-container').html(result);
                                              });
        } 
</script>
```

and then:

```
var popupTemplate = Properties.Resources.ToolbarTemplate
            .Replace("~T~", typeof (T).ToString())
            .Replace("~userID~", userID)
            .Replace("~GridName~", name)
            .Replace("~ExportAction~", String.Format("/{0}/{1}", dataAccessing.Item2, dataAccessing.Item1));
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Template(popupTemplate));
```

Answer (score 0):

For send Parameter to action with kendo DataSource use this code

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Grid").Data("additionalInfo"))
```

and in javascript get your json data

```
function additionalInfo() {
return {
    AdditionalParam : "test"
}
```

Comment: And where can I put JS? As I mentioned above, I have cs file. That's the main problem.